# Multiply 2 values from different tables and store the result in a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, calculated-columns, computed-field

**Book** (B_ID is PK)

```
| B_ID |   Name  | Unit_Price|
|------+---------+-----------|
|  B01 |   Math  |     25    |
|  B02 | Science |     34    |
```

**Order** (O_ID is PK)

```
| O_ID |   Date  | Total_Price |
|------+---------+-------------|
| O01  | 12/1/16 |    NULL     |
| O02  | 20/3/16 |    NULL     |
```

**Order Detais** (O_ID,B_ID is Composite PK where both ID are FK to tables above )

```
| O_ID | B_ID |  Quantity |
|------+------+-----------|
|  O01 |  B01 |     2     |
|  O01 |  B02 |     1     |
|  O02 |  B02 |     5     |
```

How to insert calculation into `Total_Price`(`Unit_Price` * `Quantity`) by  replacing NULL with the results of calculation. I've tried solve it by using CTE but I don't like that I need to run the CTE again to update it when new record(Exp: O03) is added.

Comment: If you *store* a computed value, you're *introducing* an opportunity for the stored, calculated, value to be inconsistent with the original base data. Ideally, don't store such values unless or until it's proven that the performance of calculating it on demand (if necessary, put the logic in a view) is inadequate. *then* consider storing the value, but if possible use built in mechanisms to ensure that the database system is maintaining that value automatically, rather than you're having to remember to recalculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment by @Damien, if you decide to not store computed values, then you can try using the following query to compute the total price for each order:

```
SELECT o.O_ID,
       SUM(od.Quantity * b.Unit_Price) AS Total_Price
FROM Order o
LEFT JOIN Order_Details od
    ON o.O_ID = od.O_ID
LEFT JOIN Book b
    ON od.B_ID = b.B_ID
GROUP BY o.O_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you colud have from idea from this:

```
create  table book (b_id char(10),name char(20),Unit_Price int)
create  table orders(o_id char(10),Date varchar(10),Total_Price int)
Create  table Order_details(o_id char(10),b_id char(10),quantity int)

insert into book values ('B01','Math'   ,25); 
insert into book values ('B02','Science',34); 

INSERT INTO orders values ( 'O01','12/1/16',NULL)                                    
INSERT INTO orders values  ('O02','20/3/16',NULL)

Insert into order_details values('O01','B01',2);
Insert into order_details values('O01','B02',1);
Insert into order_details values('O02','B02',5);




declare @total int, @o_id char(10)

declare c cursor for
select sum(a.unit_price * b.quantity),b.o_id from book a join order_details b on a.b_id=b.b_id group by b.o_id
open c
fetch next from c into @total,@o_id
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
update orders set total_price=@total where o_id=@o_id
fetch next from c into @total,@o_id
end
close c
deallocate c

select * from orders
```

Comment: I've tried to add a new record in order_details (Insert into Order_details values('O02','B01',1)) but when I run (select * from orders), the calculation result did not update.